# Non-blocking socket receive

Tags: c, sockets

I have a simple server program that looks like the code below:

```
// create, bind, listen accept etc..

while(1)
{
    UpdateData();
    int ret = send(sock, data, dataLength , 0);

    // Check if client sent "Abort" and if so, break.
}
```

Is it possible to check if any data has arrived from the client without blocking, so that the server can continuously dump data to the client?

Comment: why don't you put the loop in its own thread, rather than poll for this?

Comment: @camelccc Do you mean having send in one thread and recv in another? That could work..

Comment: @Stargateur Sorry about that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39391541/socket-client-using-select

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course, there are a lot of solutions, AFAIK:

- Thread
- Non blocking mode
- [`select()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)
- [`poll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)
- [`epoll()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)
- [`IOCP()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7313773/7076153)
- [`kqueue()`](https://people.freebsd.org/~jmg/kqueue.historic.man.html)

Not all available for all OS.

Comment: Thanks. The two first I know about, Ill have to read up on the rest.

Answer (score 1):

If your gonna define a non-blocking `socket`, you should add `SOCK_NONBLOCK` value in socket-type parameter when open a socket. for example this statement open a `RAW` socket in which can read and write `TCP` packets in non-blocking mode :

```
recv_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW | SOCK_NONBLOCK
                         , IPPROTO_TCP);
```

Then you can call `read` function as bellow :

```
typedef struct
{
    struct iphdr ip;
    struct tcphdr tcp;
    char datagram[DATAGRAM_SIZE];
} TCP_PACKET;

int ret_read = 0;
TCP_PACKET recv_packet;

ret_read = read(recv_socket, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&received_packet)
, sizeof(received_packet));

if(ret_read >= 0)
{
    // read occured in success
}
```

Notice : never use of const-size in `read` :

```
ret_read = read(recv_socket, reinterpret_cast<void*>(&received_packet)
, 65536);    // makes segmentation fault
```

it makes segmentation fault while reading packets. just use of `sizeof`.